# How to insert data in to table with a Union

Tags: sql, oracle, select, union, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert more data in to my tables, This code below works perfectly:

```
insert into GENRES (GENRES) 
SELECT GENRE1 FROM titles
union all
SELECT GENRE2 FROM titles
union all
SELECT GENRE3 FROM titles
```

However, when i try to amend it so I can insert the MOVIE_TITLE_ID with it I can an error:

```
insert into GENRES (GENRES,MOVIE_TITLE_ID) 
SELECT GENRE1 FROM titles
union all
SELECT GENRE2 FROM titles
union all
SELECT GENRE3 FROM titles
union all
select TITLE_ID
from titles;
```

Error MSG:

```
Error starting at line : 175 in command -
insert into GENRES (GENRES,MOVIE_TITLE_ID) 
SELECT GENRE1 FROM titles
union all
SELECT GENRE2 FROM titles
union all
SELECT GENRE3 FROM titles
union all
select TITLE_ID
from titles
Error at Command Line : 175 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I'm guessing I'm doing it in the wrong format, Any help will be useful!

Comment: If you specify `(GENRES,MOVIE_TITLE_ID)`, then each SELECT should provide TWO values, not one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the `union`ed subquery must return the same number of columns, with equivalent datatypes, which, in turn, must match the column list for `insert`. Your query declares two columns for insert, but the subqueries return just one column (and, possibly, the datatype of `title_id` is not the same as `genre1`).

Instead, each subquery should produce two columns: the genre, and the related title id:

```
insert into genres (genres,movie_title_id) 
select genre1, title_id from titles
union all
select genre2, title_id from titles
union all
select genre3, title_id from titles
```

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this result is through a very simple query mentioned below.

```
SELECT * INTO task_master FROM admin_task_master UNION SELECT * from manuscript_task_master order by task_type_id;
```